# geocoding addresses specifically into NAD1983 or converting X,Y into 1983 after geocoding

Tags: convert, coordinate-system, address

I'm going bananas trying to geocode addresses into a NAD1983.

I have ArcMap 10.1 and I'm using the default address locator (North American 10.0 from arcgis online).  No matter how low I set the sensitivity, it gives me "There was an error trying to process this table" when I specifically choose NAD1983.  If I allow it to create the X,Y coordinates in WGS1984, then I get coordinates...BUT my other coordinates (I'm going to measure distance/proximity) are in NAD1983.

Any suggestions? I can't figure out how to change them from WGS1984 to NAD1983 when they're in a layer, although I have changed the data frame successfully it seems...

Any guidance is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can "project" data from one coordinate system to another; for example, moving from `NAD1983` to `WGS84` (or vice versa). Then you can perform your distance calculation when both layers are in the same projection (`NAD1983` sounds like it is appropriate for your data).

More advice here: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000007m000000

Answer (score 0):

When you geocode the most common projection is likely wgs84. Once you get results you could change the projection of the data frame to be nad83 and then export the results to a feature class--make sure to use the projection of the data frame.

Comment: (1) Neither WGS84 nor NAD83 are projections: they are ellipsoidal datums.  (2) Corresponding points in these datums are typically less than than one meter apart, so for many practical purposes it is unnecessary to convert from one to the other.